# How to make a button that makes my menu open by clicking the button or even the marker in the leaflet

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, leaflet

I have exactly this sidebar https://turbo87.github.io/sidebar-v2/examples/index.html and the source code of it I removed from that github https://github.com/Turbo87/sidebar-v2/blob/master/examples/index.html and as you can see when clicking on the marker it does not do any action, I tried in many ways to make it open when clicking in the marker and bring the content, if possible show me a command to make it open by clicking on the marker thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like this to close/collapse the sidebar:

```
function showhidebar(){
button = document.getElementsByClassName('fa fa-bars')[0] 
button.click()
}

map.eachLayer(function(l){if (l instanceof L.Marker) {l.on('click', showhidebar)}});
```

Comment: thank you very much, you helped me a lot, I couldn't find a solution anywhere